How to center items in carousel slider?
I am currently working on a country flag slider with around 14 different country flags.
My desired animation is that there is a container/card showing only 3 countries on the card, where it slides after 2 seconds:
Country on the left moves out of the container
Country on the middle moves to the left
Country on the right goes to the middle and scales a little bit (so it pops a bit more out) while moving to it.
And a new country moves to the right side.
The issue I'm encountering is that I can't figure out how to center the middle image into the middle of the card, since the way I've implemented it is that there are 14 images and when I use justify-content: center;  the Philippines shows on the card in the middle which is normal but not the desired outcome.
What I have tried so far:

Using pixels and calculate the amount it has to move but this doesn't make it responsive and I would like it to be responsive.
Justify-content: center; on the div

What currently happens: [Click]
Desired animation: [Click]
This is my first Stackoverflow post and I hope I explained everything clearly, if not please feel free to give feedback on how I can improve my post.
Code:


const slider = document.querySelector('.flag-slider');
const flags = document.querySelectorAll('.flag');
let currentIndex = 2; // Middle flag

function updateFlags() {
  flags.forEach((flag, index) => {
    flag.classList.remove('active');
    if (index === currentIndex - 1) {
      flag.classList.add('active');
    }
  });
}

function slideFlags() {
  // Slide to the left
  slider.style.transform = `translateX(-${(currentIndex - 1) * (75 / 3)}%)`;

  currentIndex++;

  if (currentIndex > flags.length) {
    console.log('reset');
    currentIndex = 2;
    slider.style.transform = `translateX(0%)`;
  }

  updateFlags();
}

// Initial flag setup
updateFlags();

// Auto-slide every 2 seconds
setInterval(slideFlags, 2000);
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

.countries {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.slider-container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 50px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.flag-slider {
  display: flex;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.flag,
.last_flag {
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out, opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.flag img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.flag.active {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
<html class="no-js" lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta property="og:title" content="">
  <meta property="og:type" content="">
  <meta property="og:url" content="">
  <meta property="og:image" content="">
  <meta property="og:image:alt" content="">
  <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" sizes="any">
  <link rel="icon" href="/icon.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icon.png">
  <link rel="manifest" href="site.webmanifest">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#fafafa">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="countries">
    <div class="slider-container">
      <div class="flag-slider">
        <img class="flag" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="Australia">
        <img class="flag" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="Austria">
        <img class="flag" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="Brazil">
        <img class="flag" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="Canada">
        <img class="flag" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="France">
        <img class="flag" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="Germany">
        <img class="flag" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="India">
        <img class="flag" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="Mexico">
        <img class="flag" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="Philippines">
        <img class="flag" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="South Africa">
        <img class="flag" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="Egypt">
        <img class="flag" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="UK">
        <img class="flag" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="USA">
        <img class="flag" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="Venezuela">
        <img class="flag" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="Australia">
        <img class="last_flag" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="Austria">
      </div>
    </div>
    <span>Different countries</span>
  </div>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>



I have tried to calculate it and hard code it but it worked for a fixed width, but it didn't work if the screen was smaller.

Off (since you requested feedback): It's unnecessary to include the HTML <head> and <body> tags in the Code Snippet, as Stack Overflow won't interpret them and they only complicate the question's code unnecessarily. (Unless you have specific questions about these, but that's not the case here.) - In my answer, you'll see how much simpler the code is without them. This way, it will be easier for others to understand as well.

If you want to further develop your code, I recommend looking into the logic of the kenwheeler/slick package, alternatives: swiper, glide.

It's commendable that you're writing the carousel element yourself. I see that you're using the CSS transform property to shift the elements from their original positions. If you calculate with better values here, your element will be centered.
// Changed 75 / 3 to 100 / 3
slider.style.transform = `translateX(-${(currentIndex - 1) * (100 / 3)}%)`;

An element needs to take up one-third of 100% (33.33 %), so you will shift it by exactly that amount (depending on the index of the element).
The 75% here seems a bit unexplained to me as a starting value.


const slider = document.querySelector('.flag-slider');
const flags = document.querySelectorAll('.flag');
let currentIndex = 2; // Middle flag

function updateFlags() {
  flags.forEach((flag, index) => {
    flag.classList.remove('active');
    if (index === currentIndex - 1) {
      flag.classList.add('active');
    }
  });
}

function slideFlags() {
  // Slide to the left
  slider.style.transform = `translateX(-${(currentIndex - 1) * (100 / 3)}%)`;

  currentIndex++;

  if (currentIndex > flags.length) {
    console.log('reset');
    currentIndex = 2;
    slider.style.transform = `translateX(0%)`;
  }

  updateFlags();
}

// Initial flag setup
updateFlags();

// Auto-slide every 2 seconds
setInterval(slideFlags, 2000);
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

.countries {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.slider-container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 50px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.flag-slider {
  display: flex;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.flag,
.last_flag {
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out, opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.flag img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.flag.active {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
<div class="countries">
  <div class="slider-container">
    <div class="flag-slider">
      <img class="flag" src="https://picsum.photos/200?1" alt="Australia">
      <img class="flag" src="https://picsum.photos/200?2" alt="Austria">
      <img class="flag" src="https://picsum.photos/200?3" alt="Brazil">
      <img class="flag" src="https://picsum.photos/200?4" alt="Canada">
      <img class="flag" src="https://picsum.photos/200?5" alt="France">
      <img class="flag" src="https://picsum.photos/200?6" alt="Germany">
      <img class="flag" src="https://picsum.photos/200?7" alt="India">
      <img class="flag" src="https://picsum.photos/200?8" alt="Mexico">
      <img class="flag" src="https://picsum.photos/200?9" alt="Philippines">
      <img class="flag" src="https://picsum.photos/200?10" alt="South Africa">
      <img class="flag" src="https://picsum.photos/200?11" alt="Egypt">
      <img class="flag" src="https://picsum.photos/200?12" alt="UK">
      <img class="flag" src="https://picsum.photos/200?13" alt="USA">
      <img class="flag" src="https://picsum.photos/200?14" alt="Venezuela">
      <img class="flag" src="https://picsum.photos/200?15" alt="Australia">
      <img class="last_flag" src="https://picsum.photos/200?16" alt="Austria">
    </div>
  </div>
  <span>Different countries</span>
</div>



